# React-Router-Dom | URL Changes, but the component doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I have a list of items, in a table in React. When I click on the table `Link`, the url updates, but the component doesn't get rendered. If I refresh the component is there.

I have read that some `React-router-dom` versions have some problems, and there are a lot of solutions that are being discussed here:

`https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md`

That although is for the `Beta` Versions. I assume I need to do something with the higher order function `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`, but it doesn't work for me. On top of that, withRouter has been set up globally in the App.

```
const AppHeader = withRouter(({ history, location, ...props }) => (
  <Header {...props} currentRoute={location.pathname} />
));
```

The thing is, my App has several applications. One Angular and 2 React ones. Do I need to set it up, on each application as well? This is the Parent Component with the router for the application the Links aren't working.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import 'react-tagsinput/react-tagsinput.css';

import PolicyRoutes from 'dataprotection/policies/containers/PolicyRoutes';

import './styles.scss';

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/policies" component={PolicyRoutes} />
    <Redirect to="/policies" />
  </Switch>
);

AppRouter.propTypes = {};

function mapStateToProps() {
  return {};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppRouter);
```

I have tried 2 solutions. The first is to actually wrap my component `withRouter` like so:

```
<Route exact path="/policies" component={withRouter(PolicyRoutes)} />
```

And the second is to wrap `withRouter`, the connect function. Both aren't working.

This is the component not working:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import OverviewScreen from '../OverviewScreen';
import PolicyDetailsScreen from '../PolicyDetailsScreen';

const PolicyRoutes = ({ match }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${match.url}/details/:policyId`} component={PolicyDetailsScreen} />
    <Route exact path={match.url} component={OverviewScreen} />
    <Redirect to={match.url} />
  </Switch>
);

PolicyRoutes.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.object
};

export default PolicyRoutes;
```

Can anyone help? I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: If you are trying to match ```/policies``` and ```/policies/details/:itemId```, maybe remove the exact param from the top Route that points to PolicyRoutes

Comment: That doesn't work either. I tried that also...

Comment: The thing is, the only change that happened to the app, is applying prettier tonit. I gone through it manually, and it isn't working. 2 weeks ago it was fine. Even try to downgrade react-router-dom and nothing ...

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a PolicyDetailsScreen component imported. Just ItemDetailsScreen.

Comment: I has just been renamed. The actual components are correctly imported. The app works. Just not `onClick` but `on refresh`. I will update the description to match them